# Using Git To Push To Github An Error Occurs

Tags: git, github, git-gui

So my files are uploaded onto the git-GUI.  Pressing commit works fine. The push button is clicked and it ask for my destination repository, so I put https://github.com/myusername/reposistoryname and then press enter, afterwards it asks for my username and password.  After those items had been entered in, I get this error message.

```
Pushing to https://github.com/myusername/reposistoryname
To https://github.com/myusername/reposistoryname
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/emaoll/pnz'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I have a github account as well as a repository on github.

Comment: It tells you what you should do!

Answer (score 0):

You got it written... Commit your changes and then pull data. After successful pull you can push your data again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate the changes in the remote brance (just like the message said), if you want to bring the changes and look it, you have to use..

```
git fetch origin //Bring all the changes from the remote server
```

But, you want to push your local changes, then you must have to use...

```
git pull //Fetch down new data  from remote server
```

after that, you can use normally the 'git push' command. Actually you can use also...

```
git status //This command bring to you some help, about what's next.
```

> I recommended to you, that use (write those commands) Git Bash (command line), - to me- it's more easy. Or if you want, use Git-GUI, just go to **Remote Menu > Fetch**

Regards!